# SQL table to Python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a SQL database from which I need to analyze a very big table. I would like to use python for that.

Unfortunately I cannot access the SQL database directly via python.

Are there any suggestions to what to export the table to be able to work with it?

1. I tried to export to SQL file and to import that into pandas dataframe but of course out of memory.
2. I tried to access the database from python directly using pymysql using

   ```
    db=pymysql.connect(host="localhost", db="all_data")
   ```

but I get "can't connect to MySQL server Win Error 10061"?

File type is `.sql`.

Many thanks

Comment: Try to export as CSV or similar than load into Pandas

Comment: What is the database type?

Comment: it is a .sql file

Comment: No, apologies.  What type of database is it; Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, etc.?   Each has its own method for exporting data, some easier to work with than others.

Comment: ah sorry, mysql

Comment: the database is on my computer locally

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before...
Try this:

```
#import libraries
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

#set login parameters
db = #enter your database schema name here
user = #enter username to login
pw = #type the password here


#connect to database
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                        .format(user=user,pw=pw, db=db))


#load data from MySQL into a dataframe
df = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from table", engine)
```

Comment: Just a note: the sqlalchemy and pymysql imports are not needed.  Neither is the explicit connect command.  Just `df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)` will do the job.  Additionally, user might need to add the database port to the connstr.

Comment: I have no user name or pwd, as I normally just open via MySQL

Comment: How could I find the database port?

Comment: It’s 3306 by default.

Comment: Thank you @S3DEV! I ran in my computer with your feedback and you are right! I updated the answer to reflect your inputs.

Comment: Nice one.  This is nearly the same as the answer I was going to post.  You beat me to it.  Upvoted.

Comment: what do I do with username and pw if I am not aware of any? I can just open the database locally

Comment: Unfortunately I still get errors after the df = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from table", engine) command....

Comment: Background on this erroe at http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8 i says

Comment: Are you able to connect? can you paste here the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure something like this would work

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\testdb.accdb;')

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''select
product_name,
product_price_per_unit,
units_ordered,
((units_ordered) * (product_price_per_unit)) AS revenue
from tracking_sales''', conn)

df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['field1','field2',...])
```

You can see a good example on this link: https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: This is for Access and OP is using MySQL; therefore this will not work.